# Is there an extension of the concept of Stokes lines/the Stokes phenomenon to 2 complex variables?

Tags: complex-analysis, differential-geometry, several-complex-variables

For one complex variable, normally we refer to the stokes(/antistokes) lines as being lines that divide the input space according to asymptotic behaviour.

I hope we can extend this idea to "stokes surfaces", manifolds of dimension $<4$ that we can use to classify the input  space. Has there been any work done on this area?